# How to open print-preview page upon clicking on hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Every browser has print preview command in their File menu I want to make "print" button on HTML page and upon clicking i want to open print preview page. is this possible?

With this we can open print options 
`<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print this page</a>`

but can we open print-preview page instead print options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.print()` is the only print-related function in [window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp).

However, if you have defined a dedicated css-file for print, you can create a page that simulates a print-preview by only using the print stylesheet. And then open this in a popup or new window.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. However there is a way to show that in IE by using ActiveX and some others for other browsers...